# symfony jquery password validation

Tags: jquery, validation, symfony, passwords

I want to validate the confirmation of my password and dispaly a message to confirm that my password are the same:

this is my code:

in Twig:

```
{#password#}
          {{ form_label(form.password.first,'Votre adresse password *') }}
          {{ form_widget(form.password.first,{'attr':{'id':'passwd1'}}) }}<br/>

{#password confirmation#}
          {{ form_label(form.password.second,'Confirmer Votre adresse password*') }}
          {{ form_widget(form.password.second,{'attr':{'id':'passwd2'}}) }}<br/>
```

in formRype:

```
$builder
             ->add('phone', 'text', array('error_bubbling' => true))
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques',
            'options' => array('required' => true),
            'first_options' => array(),
            'second_options' => array(),
            'error_bubbling'=>true
        ))
```

and jquery:

```
function validateMainForm() {

    jQuery("#form_register").validate({
        /*Gestion des règles de controle*/
        rules: {
              'contact[phone]': {
                required: true,
                'regex': /^0[1-9][0-9]{8}$/
            },


            'contact[datacontact][email][first]': {
                required: true,
                'email': true,
                maxlength: 50


            },
            'contact[datacontact][email][second]': {
                required: true,
                'email': true,
                maxlength: 50

            },
            'contact[password][first]': {
                required: true

            },

            'contact[password][second]': {
                equalTo:'#contact[password][first]'


            },
```

the email is correct, but the password no.
How I can validate my password?

Comment: Can you add more detail about what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I want to display a message that inform me if the password and the confirmation password are the same like this, ![enter image description here][1]

This is the code of my form Type:

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

```
    $builder
             ->add('phone', 'text', array('error_bubbling' => true))
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques',
            'options' => array('required' => true),
            'first_options' => array(),
            'second_options' => array(),
            'error_bubbling'=>true
        ))
            ->add('datacontact', new DataContactType($this->fields));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Model\Contact'
    ));
}

public function getName() {
    return 'contact';
}
```

I want to display a message that inform me if the password and the confirmation password are the same like this, ![enter image description here][1]

This is the code of my form Type:

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

```
$builder
         ->add('phone', 'text', array('error_bubbling' => true))
    ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'invalid_message' => 'les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques',
        'options' => array('required' => true),
        'first_options' => array(),
        'second_options' => array(),
        'error_bubbling'=>true
    ))
        ->add('datacontact', new DataContactType($this->fields));
```

}

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'contact'
    ));
}

public function getName() {
    return 'contact';
}
```

and this is the code of my form_widget:

```
{#password#} {{ form_label(form.password.first,'Votre adresse password *') }} {{ form_widget(form.password.first,{'attr':{'id':'password','name':'password'}}) }}

{#password confirmation#} {{ form_label(form.password,'Confirmer Votre adresse password*') }} {{ form_widget(form.password.second,{'attr':{'id':'password1', 'name':'password1'}}) }}
```

Jquery Method

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexp) {

    if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
        regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
    else if (regexp.global)
        regexp.lastIndex = 0;
    return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
}, "");


jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    'ContainsAtLeastOneDigit',
    function (value) {
        return /[0-9]/.test(value);
    },
    'Your password must contain at least one digit.'
);

jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    'ContainsAtLeastOneCapitalLetter',
    function (value) {
        return /[A-Z]/.test(value);
    },
    'Your password must contain at least one capital letter.'
);
jQuery.validator.addMethod( 'passwordMatch', function(value, element) {

    // The two password inputs

  var pass1 = $('input[name="contact[password][first"]').attr('value');
   var pass2 = $('input[name="contact[password][second"]').attr('value');
    // Check for equality with the password inputs
    if (pass1 != pass2 ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}, "Your Passwords Must Match");
```

So I need to display a message informing me if my confirmation password are the same or not.